# Rename files in bash scripted based on file modified date

Tags: scripting, rename

It has been awhile since I have had to drive into shell scripting. However, I have a shell script where I'm renaming files based on the file extension from a ftp upload.

Currently, the files are uploaded to the server via an FTP process. All files are renamed from **filename.txt** to **filename.dat**. What I would like to do is only rename the files based on the file's modified date after a certain number of minutes.

i.e. all files whose modified time is greater than five (5) minutes.
-mtime -5.

Below is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in /u/easy/ep2/data/download/*.txt; do
    newname=${name%.txt}.log
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `+5` for more than 5 minutes.

```
find /u/easy/ep2/data/download -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -mtime +5 \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.txt}.log"' arg0ignored {} \;
```

**Edit**

Example:

```
$ find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -mtime +5 -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.txt}.log"' x0 '{}' \;
mv /tmp/1.txt /tmp/1.log
mv /tmp/2.txt /tmp/2.log
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the Linux version. We are running RedHat Enterprise v 7.4.

Comment: This is the error message I get when I run the script from the command line or inside the script.  **find: paths must precede expression:  -exec**

Comment: I have GNU find 4.6.0, for me this works. I forgot the arg0, that is ignored, but that shouldn't lead to this message.

Comment: I will give that a try! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Still returns the same error message when I added the arg0ignored.

Comment: Can you run it in a script with `set -x` or invoked with `bash -x` and show the output?

Comment: ++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' rhadmin gamora '~'
[rhadmin@gamora ~]$ bash -x newRenameDataFilesToTxt.sh      
+ bash -x newRenameDataFilesToTxt.sh    
+ find /u/easy/ep2/data/download -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' -mtime +1 ' -exec' sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.log}.stan"' '{};'  
find: paths must precede expression:  -exec      
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]         
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' rhadmin gamora '~'     
[rhadmin@gamora ~]$

Comment: I changed the file extensions to test with dummy files.

Comment: There is a space before ` -exec`. Write the whole command on one line, I just added the line break for readability.

Comment: I can get it to run at the command prompt with -mtime now. I am trying to rename the files based off the minutes modified, but the following error appears. mv: cannot stat ``: No such file or directory. It appears four (4) times. I have four .log files in the directory. I changed -mtime +5 to -mmin +5.

Comment: Try is with `... -exec sh -xc 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.txt}.log"' arg0ignored {} \;` for debugging.

Comment: Here is the output +mv '' .stan then the error message appears.

Comment: It appears the $1 is not passing the value to ${1%.log}.stan. When I replace the mv to echo it displays .stan.

Comment: I don't know where your `.stan` comes from. I added an example for /tmp with the output, it works for me. Copy the line as it is and see what happens.

Comment: It was just a dummy file extension I was using for testing.

Comment: I got the same error /tmp/block_semaphore.log: ${1.log}.txt: bad substitution.

Comment: It is `${1%.txt}.log`. Maybe your `sh` is not `bash`. Try `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Forgot to include that. When I changed it to use bash, instead of sh, it just displays -- mv .log four (4) times. Unsure why the file is not being passed to $1.